# Performance with MS concurrency::parallel_for() for a single iteration

Tags: c++, visual-c++, parallel-processing

I suppose there have been numerous questions regarding performance issues while trying to achieve concurrency with `parallel_for`. Even I have noted a performance drop while trying to parallelize memory-access extensive `for` loops using `parallel_for`. The application area that I am working on is image processing.

Surprisingly this performance drop is seen even if I create a loop with a single iteration to be processed by `parallel_for`!!

What I mean is that I have a code block as under, which executes in 7 sec without any parallelisation

```
<code block without parallelisation>   //(Executes in 7 seconds)
```

If I enclose the above code within a `parallel_for` loop as under, the performance increases to 18 seconds.

```
parallel_for(0,1,[&](int random_var){   //(Executes in 18 seconds)
<code block without parallelisation> 
});
```

I completely fail to understand such a behaviour. What could cause such a huge overhead for the processing. In such a case I assume there should not be any memory bandwidth related issues?

Let me know in case you require more information for this specific problem that I am facing.

Comment: Well, is your algorithm *actually* parallel or is it crippled by heavy sharing?

Comment: Well, there is a good scope for parallelisation, since pixel values are not inter-dependent. But surely there is heavy sharing of input data for each pixel's calculation.

Comment: But my point is, why does all that even matter, if all I am doing is create a single iteration inside parallel_for!

Comment: because even for one iteration inside parallel_for its going to execute your code in a thread. so there will be preemption with main thread. also there are other thread related book keeping works, that will take time.

Answer (score 0):

because even for one iteration inside parallel_for its going to execute your code in a thread. so there will be preemption with main thread. also there are other thread related book keeping works, that will take time.

Comment: If we have to do with such big overheads for a simple thread creation, why would we want to use parallel_for at all...

Comment: the extra time its taking is probably not due to thread creation. however that's an extra overhead that must be occurring. When you run your code in thread then it runs paralally with other threads (main thread) So there will be a context switching. and processor will not be executing only your code all the time. So the 17 seconds you are seeing is not the time that it takes to execute only your code. its the time when your job is finished while doing some other tasks in parallal

Comment: I see. In such a case, how can I ensure good performance for my parallel_for loop. Is there some sort of thread priority which can set? Also, you may note that my application doesn't have any other threads running in parallel. In case it's the other system processes which is slowing it up, they should have taken effect even without the parallel_for loop?

Comment: Your application have an other thread that is the main thread of execution, and parallal_for executes your code in a thread different to that. In multithreading environment you always have more that one thread and all are simultaneously working. However you may sleap an waiting thread. If you really need to get the job in parallal you mean you have to run two jobs concurrently. and If you don't really need concurrency don't use threads. execute them in main thread of execution.